# “ValueError: multiclass format is not supported” xgb.XGBClassifier

Tags: python, xgboost

Первый раз решаю задачу многоклассовой классификации. Есть Значения X и Y, у которого на выходе 5 значений [0,1,2,3,4]. При запуске ругается, что это multiclass format is not supported. Понимаю что надо куда-то впихнуть в  xgb_params еще num_class, но если вписываю 'num_class': range(0,5,1) то ругается Invalid parameter num_class for estimator XGBClassifier. Уже второй день читаю, понимаю, что простая вещь, но не могу понять что делаю не так.

```
xgb_model = xgb.XGBClassifier(objective='multi:softmax')

xgb_params  = [
{
"n_estimators": range(50, 501, 50),
}
]
cv = cross_validation.StratifiedShuffleSplit(y_train, n_iter=5, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)

xgb_grid = grid_search.GridSearchCV(xgb_model, xgb_params, scoring='roc_auc', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1, verbose=3)
xgb_grid.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Вот пример данных

```
                          X                                     Y
-1.35173485 1.50224188  2.04951167  0.43759658  0.24381777      2
2.81047260  1.31259056  1.39265240  0.16384002  0.65438366      3
2.32878809  -1.92845940 -2.06453246 0.73132270  0.11771229      2
-0.12810555 -2.07268765 -2.40760215 0.97855042  0.11144164      1
1.88682063  0.75792329  -0.09754671 0.46571931  0.62111648      2
-1.09361266 1.74758304  2.49960891  0.36679883  0.88895562      2
0.71760095  -1.30711698 -2.15681966 0.33700593  0.07171119      2
4.60060308  -1.60544855 -1.88996123 0.94500124  0.63776116      4
-0.84223064 2.78233537  3.07299711  0.31470071  0.34424704      1
-0.71236435 0.53140549  0.46677096  0.12320728  0.58829090      2
-0.35333909 1.12463059  1.70104349  0.89084673  0.16585229      2
3.04322100  -1.36878116 -2.31056167 0.81178387  0.04095645      1
-1.04088918 -1.97497570 -1.93285343 0.54101882  0.02528487      1
-0.41624939 0.54592833  0.95458283  0.40004902  0.55062705      2
-1.77706795 0.29061278  0.68186697  0.17430716  0.75095729      0
```

Comment: вы можете привести небольшой пример данных, чтобы можно было воспроизвести ошибку?

Comment: Если вопрос с ошибкой, то добавляйте к вопросу также и стек исключения